# devtool and SourceMapDevToolPlugin,are they all needed?

Tags: webpack

If I have used **SourceMapDevToolPlugin** to make a configuration for sourcemap,do I still need to add a **devtool** key in **webpack.config.js**?

Answer (score 9):

No, you don't need to if you are satisfied with the generated source maps with the current configuration.

**SourceMapDevToolPlugin** gives you a little bit more control over generating source maps. With the plugin you can generate source maps only for the portions of your code. It allows you to specify which files to match using regular expression for instance (exactly as with loaders).

With `devtool` property, webpack matches only .js and .css files by default and it generates source map for every module. Under the hood [it maps to the SourceMapDevToolPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/f4c04d8f98c023f1ff7e06642133ea5ee6f107f3/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js#L213).